# self join query issues with PostGIS

Tags: sql, geospatial, postgis

I have a table and I am doing a self join on it with geo-spacial functions fro PostgreSQL. Now I am expecting to build the point of intersections of each intersection except for those that has the attribute 'tunnel_road' having same values.

Therefore I have two rows conatining the value 'tunnel' which I don't want to build a point of intersection between them.

The query I am using is the following, though it is not working properly since it still is creating a point of intersection between the two lines.

```
insert into temp_intersect
select nextval('road_intersection_id_seq'), a.road_id, b.road_id, st_intersection(a.road, b.road), st_centroid(st_intersection(a.road, b.road))
from polygon_road a, polygon_road b
where st_intersects(a.road, b.road) AND a.road_id < b.road_id AND a.tunnel_road != b.tunnel_road
```

Any suggestions please?

the following is the table from which I am getting my data. As one can notice there is two rows containing the same value for the tunnel_road column where there is the id = 47 and 73

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some sample data, the results you are seeking, and the results you are seeing with this query?

Comment: I have edited the question with the table i am using @PinnyM

Comment: The result is including a point of intersection with the two rows having the value 'tunnel' which this i don't want to happen

Comment: It is creating a point of intersection between road_id = 52 and road_id = 73 , which are both containing the value 'tunnel' and is expected to be skipped but for some reason it is being executed also.

Comment: Can you repost the data in text form to make it easier to copy over?

Comment: Can you run the following `SELECT CASE WHEN a.tunnel_road = b.tunnel_road THEN 'Are Equal' ELSE 'Not Equal' END FROM polygon_road a, polygon_road b WHERE a.road_id = 52 AND b.road_id = 73` this will tell you if they are equal. We can work out the join after that

Comment: Using a sqlfiddle with a [similar schema](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/b3ac7/2), I'm not seeing the results that you are.  Perhaps you can make a fiddle of your schema, data, and query to more accurately represent your isue?

Comment: @IT_info if you got it to work I would suggest posting the solution as an answer. Otherwise this question is useless on SO

Comment: Have you tried using <> instead of !=?  I imagine you get the same result, but just checking.